# node-gyp and node-pre-gyp errors with npm install on Mint 17.2

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-gyp

Ok, I'm pulling my hair out, been stuck on this for 2 straight days.

I started working on a MEAN project again after a couple months away and am getting tons of node-gyp errors on npm install.

I can attach the whole output if helpful but here are the modules that are having issues:

```
> kerberos@0.0.11 install /home/me/node/abc/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

> kerberos@0.0.11 install /home/me/node/abc/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

> bson@0.2.22 install /home/me/node/abc/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

> bson@0.2.22 install /home/me/node/abc/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

> ws@0.4.32 install /home/me/node/abc/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

> ws@0.4.32 install /home/me/node/abc/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

> lwip@0.0.6 install /home/me/node/abc/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-expressjs/node_modules/lwip
> node-gyp rebuild

> v8-debug@0.4.6 install /home/me/node/abc/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

> v8-profiler@5.2.12 install /home/me/node/abc/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-profiler
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! v8-profiler@5.2.12 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-profiler@5.2.12 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the v8-profiler package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-profiler
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've seriously tried everything I can think of:

- Clean installs of Mint 17, 17.1, & 17.2
- Node versions 0.10.x - 5.1 (like literally almost every version between) installed using Mint software manager, curl, wget, and NVM 
  (the package.json wants node 0.12.x and npm 2.12.x fwiw)
- Damn near every NPM version
- Tried installing diff versions of Python as well as setting npm config to point to Python 2, 2.7, and 3
- Tried installing affected dependencies globally
- Tried the 'sudo npm explore npm -g --npm install node-gyp@latest' fix
- Tried messing with affected dependency version numbers in package.json, changing '~' to '>=' a la russfrisch solution here: https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-debug/issues/7

I'm done :(  Need help please!

Comment: Have you tried installing node-gyp globally with -g option? Do you have make and proper C/C++ compilers installed? As stated here [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp), the correct python version is 2.7 (3.x is not supported). You can install compilers and make using: apt-get install build-essential

Comment: Yes, have tried all of that and have tried installing reinstalling g++ compilers, make, build essential etc plus several 2.x versions of pything including 2.7.  Thanks though.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you need to install visual studio c++ compilers in order to get it working properly. Try that.